# Implementing CodeMirror into Widget backend form not updating texarea

Tags: javascript, wordpress, codemirror

I'm trying to wrap my head around how this actually works in wordpress on the admin back end for a widget I'm trying to create (similar to the custom HTML widget). I've read a few tutorials but the information seems to change and I feel I have just confused myself.

Everything works fine while initializing codemirror and it is applied to the textarea but the errors I'm having are:

1. When new html is entered into codemirror the save button for the widget doesn't activate.
2. If I change another field to activate the save button the data from codemirror is not sent or saved.

   ```
   (function ($) {
       $(document).ready( function(){
           var editorSettings = wp.codeEditor.defaultSettings ? _.clone( wp.codeEditor.defaultSettings ) : {};
           editorSettings.codemirror = _.extend(
               {},
               editorSettings.codemirror,
               {
                   lineNumbers: true,
                   mode: "text/html",
                   indentUnit: 2,
                   tabSize: 2,
                   autoRefresh:true,
               }
           );
           var editor = wp.codeEditor.initialize( $('#<?php echo $textarea_id; ?>'), editorSettings );  
       });
   })(jQuery);
   </script>
   ```

   I've also tried adding:

   ```
    $(document).on('keyup', '.CodeMirror-code', function(){
         editor.codemirror.save();
         $('#<?php echo $textarea_id; ?>').html(editor.codemirror.getValue());
     });
   ```

but editor.codemirror.getValue() return empty when I display through console.log

Code for Textarea

```
   <p>
       <label for="<?php echo $textarea_id; ?>"><?php _e( 'Locked Content:' ); ?></label>
       <textarea id="<?php echo $textarea_id; ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'locked-content' ); ?>" class="widefat"><?php echo esc_textarea( $instance['locked-content'] ); ?></textarea>
    </p>
```

Any help (links to a proper tutorial, advice  etc) would be much appreciated JS isn't my strongest language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this came down to me being an idiot lol I was calling this same block of code from another widget as I was trying to make both widgets textareas into codemirrors.

I changed the name of 2 variables to be more specific towards the widget eg:

```
var editorSettings    
var editor
```

where changed to:

```
var cm_editorSettings    
var cm_editor
```

This allowed me to us cm.editor.codemirror.getValue() and return the actual value. Still not sure if this is the correct way to implement it so please correct me if I am wrong but currently the working code to update the textarea and enable save button is as follows

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready( function(){
          var cm_editorSettings = wp.codeEditor.defaultSettings ? _.clone( wp.codeEditor.defaultSettings ) : {};
            cm_editorSettings.codemirror = _.extend(
                {},
                cm_editorSettings.codemirror,
                {
                    lineNumbers: true,
                    mode: "text/html",
                    indentUnit: 2,
                    tabSize: 2,
                    autoRefresh:true,
                }
            );
        var cm_editor = wp.codeEditor.initialize($('#<?php echo $textarea_id; ?>') , cm_editorSettings );
        $(document).on('keyup', '.CodeMirror-code', function(){
            $('#<?php echo $textarea_id; ?>').html(cm_editor.codemirror.getValue());
            $('#<?php echo $textarea_id; ?>').trigger('change');
        });

    });
})(jQuery);
```